# Convert IQueryable to Custom Class

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, mvvm

I have a LINQ query as below,

```
public AddXferData DisplayXferDataToBeModified(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            var resultSet = (from items in DataContext.Transfers
                             where items.Transfer_ID.Equals(ID)
                             select new AddXferData
                             {
                                 XferID = items.Transfer_ID,
                                 LogicalName = items.Logical_Name,
                                 RoutCode = items.Route_Code,
                                 Label = items.Label,
                                 OnNetDNA = items.On_Net_DNA,
                                 OnNetDNB = items.On_Net_DNB,
                                 FailMessage = items.Failure_Message,
                             });
            return resultSet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

But my resultSet asks for a Cast and the message I get is

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'ICMAdministration.Data.AddXferData'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

I need to cast the resultset to type AddXferData. Can you let me know how this can be achieved. Your help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Regards,
Raghu

Comment: And you expect just a single `AddXferData`?

Answer (score 6):

If it's a single `AddXferData`, then try:

```
return resultSet.First();
```

or

```
return resultSet.FirstOrDefault();
```

If it can return `null` (as in `ID` not found or something)

Answer (score 3):

```
return resultSet.SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

your query will return the collection of AddXferData objects. if you dont expect single result , change the function signature.

```
 public list<AddXferData> DisplayXferDataToBeModified(int ID)
```

and return the list
     resultSet.ToList();